# Assigning ID of created record in Salesforce Flow without assigning values manually

Tags: screen-flow, salesforce-flow

I am trying to basically Clone a record so I do a simple GET and then Create the record from that GET data.

- Still, when trying to access the ID of this newly created Opportunity I get 'True' as the value is supposed to record itself or its ID so I can do a get with that newly created ID.
- Is there a way to do this without having to manually assign values to each field I have over 200 fields that I need to copy over.
  recordId variable is already in use by the button I launch this flow from so I can't re-use that I tested using recordId variable but it's hit and miss.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you're going to run into read-only fields like formulas, audit fields, etc. Flows don't have a way to manipulate fields dynamically. You're going to need some help. Fortunately, we can call Apex, so we can add a custom action:

```
public class StripInaccessibleAction {
    public class Input {
        @InvocableVariable(
            description='The record to clean up'
            label='Record'
            required=true
        )
        public sObject record;
        @InvocableVariable(
            description='The access type to use'
            label='Access Type'
            required=true
        )
        // CREATABLE, READABLE, UPDATABLE, UPSERTABLE
        public String accessType;
    }
    public class Output {
        @InvocableVariable(description='The cleaned record' label='Result Record')
        public sObject record;
    }
    @InvocableMethod(
        label='Strip Inaccessible Fields'
        description='Removes fields that the the user cannot edit'
    )
    public static Output[] processRecords(Input[] requests) {
        Output[] results = new Output[0];
        Boolean hasPersonAccountsEnabled = sObjectType.Account.fields.getMap()
            .containsKey('IsPersonAccount');
        for (Input request : requests) {
            sObject record = request.record.clone(true, false, false);
            Boolean isPersonAccount =
                request.record.getSObjectType() == Account.sObjectType &&
                hasPersonAccountsEnabled &&
                record.get('IsPersonAccount') == true;
            AccessType recordAccessType = AccessType.valueOf(request.accessType);
            SObjectAccessDecision decisions = Security.stripInaccessible(
                recordAccessType,
                new List<SObject>{ record }
            );
            Output result = new Output();
            result.record = clearNullFields(
                decisions.getRecords()[0],
                recordAccessType,
                isPersonAccount
            );
            results.add(result);
        }
        return results;
    }
    static Set<String> standardPersonFields = new Set<String>{
        'FirstName',
        'MiddleName',
        'LastName',
        'Suffix',
        'Salutation'
    };
    static sObject clearNullFields(
        sObject record,
        AccessType recordAccessType,
        Boolean isPersonAccount
    ) {
        sObjectType newSObjectType = record.getSObjectType();
        sObject result = newSObjectType.newSObject(record.Id);
        Map<String, Object> values = record.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
        Map<String, SObjectField> fields = newSObjectType.getDescribe()
            .fields.getMap();
        Boolean isInsert =
            recordAccessType == AccessType.CREATABLE ||
            recordAccessType == AccessType.UPSERTABLE;
        Boolean isUpdate =
            recordAccessType == AccessType.UPDATABLE ||
            recordAccessType == AccessType.UPSERTABLE;
        for (String field : values.keySet()) {
            DescribeFieldResult describe = fields.get(field).getDescribe();
            Boolean availableForInsert = isInsert && describe.isCreateable();
            Boolean availableForUpdate = isUpdate && describe.isUpdateable();
            Boolean skipPersonField =
                !isPersonAccount &&
                (field.endsWith('__pc') ||
                field.endsWith('__ps') ||
                standardPersonFields.contains(field));
            if ((availableForInsert || availableForUpdate) && !skipPersonField) {
                result.put(field, values.get(field));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/89b79cae9087fc5627c5ee63653c8de3).

Using this code, you can get the record, pass it through this method, and then update the records. Here's my proof of concept flow:

[image: Updated Flow to Demonstrate Cloning]

Edit: Updated the code to support person accounts, and updated the graphic to reflect that the Id field must be cleared out for cloning.

Note that the output record from the Apex Action is the record you'll want to use for the Create Record flow.

Comment: Hi there, 
Is this code goignt o clear our the recordid variable so the created new recordid be saved in there?

Comment: @SimpleCode I edited this answer with a newer version of the code that supports Person Accounts. I also updated the graphic to visualize the flow. The "recordId" variable isn't updated by the DML operation. In this flow, you first get the record, then pass that into the Apex Action. The output from that Apex Action is the record you'll use to create a new record. After the create element is run, the newly created record ID will be in the record variable that was used to create the record. recordID is not updated as a result.